# Counting the min (or max) number of the occurrence of a word across multiple columns in sql

Tags: count

I'm teaching myself SQL and Excel and I'm trying to practice using some data sets.

Please help me with this thought. I'm trying to create this new column called "Flu". I need to count the min number of the occurrence of the word "true" across 3 columns and then based on this number populate this new column "Flu". I'm thinking something like below:

CASE
WHEN MIN (# of "true") >=2 THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS "FLU"

But my understanding is that CASE WHEN works down a column and not necesarrily across columns. I appreciate your comments.

was thinking of a conditional statement such as:

CASE
WHEN MIN (# of "true") >=2 THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS "FLU"

Comment: I ran this code and it seems it's doing the job. But was wondering if there could be a compact way to accomplish the same result:       SELECT
CASE
 WHEN(
  (case when fever = true then 1 else 0 end) 
+ (case when cough = true then 1 else 0 end)
+ (case when fatigue=true then 1 else 0 end)  )>=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
AS flu_sym
FROM  `my_table`
ORDER BY flu_sym DESC